Armature bones warp entire mesh and it doesnt even stays inside mesh after automatic weights
Im trying to rig my little mesh but every time i try to use automatic weights and try pose mode my bones deform the entire mesh and the limbs that are supposed to be rigged dont even follow the bone, it twirls and turns the entire mesh some how and i dont know what to do


Hello, it's probably because the normals of your object are inverted, go in Edit mode, select all, press Shift N and parent again, if it doesn't work please share your file

That worked!! i have no idea why it does that!! but thank you very much!!

It's because the normals of your object are inverted, go in Edit mode, select all, press Shift N and parent again.
